# AS3: Add Timer to running a function

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I'm trying to create a simple Timer for running a function. You can see in below :

I would like to run `DiceOne` and `DieTwo` animations for a while.

```
rollBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rollBtnClicked);

function rollBtnClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    rollNum1 = rollDice();
    rollNum2 = rollDice();

    throwDice();

    var myTimerStop:Timer = new Timer(2000); // 2 seconds
    myTimerStop.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, throwDiceStop);
    myTimerStop.start();

    DiceOne.gotoAndStop(rollNum1);
    DiceTwo.gotoAndStop(rollNum2);
}
function throwDice():void {
    DiceOne.gotoAndPlay(0);
    DiceTwo.gotoAndPlay(0);
}
function throwDiceStop(event:TimerEvent):void {
    DiceOne.stop();
    DiceTwo.stop();
}
```

But above statements won't work. Please tell me what am i missing here.

Any helps would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You immediately order your dice to stop right below starting the timer. Remove these statements and relocate them into `throwDiceStop()` function. Also, it'll be better if you use `flash.utils.setTimeout()` to set a one-time timer, because in the other case you could mis-create a timer or fail to properly handle its deactivation (I see you don't do it properly, BTW).

```
function rollBtnClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    throwDice();
    setTimeout(throwDiceStop,2000);
}
function throwDice():void {
    DiceOne.play(); // don't get started with 0, as it'll end you up 
    // with consistent animation through different throws
    DiceTwo.play();
}
function throwDiceStop():void {
    rollNum1 = rollDice();
    rollNum2 = rollDice();
    DiceOne.gotoAndStop(rollNum1); // and only here select proper values for dice
    DiceTwo.gotoAndStop(rollNum2);
    // inform the game about the dice finally settling, TODO
}
```